# Is it possible to consecutively debug configurations in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

In VSCode, I would like to automate the debugging of node scripts **consecutively** instead of manually selecting configurations.  In the terminal, one would run `node program1.js && node program2.js`.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) if you want them to run in parallel

Comment: I'm not trying to run them in parallel -- I'm trying to run them **consecutively**; i.e one after another.

Comment: You can put them in npm scripts and run a third npm script which calls both scrips with && in between like you mentioned